# How to Get A Element First Child Text Using Jquery And Class Selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Have Two Element Inside a Element. like below =>

```
<div class="NDateCount" style="display:inline-block">
     <!--Issue to solve-->
     <small style="display:none;" class="ng-binding">2017-07-08T12:44:10.367+06:00</small>
     <small ng-show="CountPostDate(post.timelineStrore.creationDate) < 2" style="color:#1ab394;" class="ng-binding"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 hours ago</small>
     <!--End of Issue to solve-->
</div>
```

i have this kind of div more than 10 time with is generating dynamically. and i want first child of `div` element which is `small` text; and i have done so far ==>

```
    var ReloadTime = function () {
        $('.NDateCount').each(function () {
            var OldValue = $(this).first().text();
            alert(OldValue);
         });
        setTimeout(ReloadTime, 50);
    }
```

but the above function giving something like both `small` tag innner text.
like ==>
[image: result]

is there ant way to solve this problem......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
var ReloadTime = function () {
    $('.NDateCount').each(function () {
        var OldValue = $(this).find('small').eq(0).text();
        alert(OldValue);
     });
    setTimeout(ReloadTime, 50);
}
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

[`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) is returning the `div` element and therefore you get the text within it.

Get the `children` of `$(this)` and then use `first()`:

```
var OldValue = $(this).children().first().text();
```

```js
var ReloadTime = function() {
  $('.NDateCount').each(function() {
    var OldValue = $(this).children().first().text();
    alert(OldValue);
  });
  //setTimeout(ReloadTime, 50);
}

ReloadTime();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="NDateCount" style="display:inline-block">
  <!--Issue to solve-->
  <small style="display:none;" class="ng-binding">2017-07-08T12:44:10.367+06:00</small>
  <small ng-show="CountPostDate(post.timelineStrore.creationDate) < 2" style="color:#1ab394;" class="ng-binding"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 hours ago</small>
  <!--End of Issue to solve-->
</div>
<div class="NDateCount" style="display:inline-block">
  <!--Issue to solve-->
  <small style="display:none;" class="ng-binding">2017-07-08T12:44:10.367+06:00</small>
  <small ng-show="CountPostDate(post.timelineStrore.creationDate) < 2" style="color:#1ab394;" class="ng-binding"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 hours ago</small>
  <!--End of Issue to solve-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ReloadTime = function () {
        $('.NDateCount').each(function () {
            var OldValue = $(this).find('small').first().text();
            alert(OldValue);
         });
    }

setTimeout(ReloadTime, 50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="NDateCount" style="display:inline-block">
     <!--Issue to solve-->
     <small style="display:none;" class="ng-binding">2017-07-08T12:44:10.367+06:00</small>
     <small ng-show="CountPostDate(post.timelineStrore.creationDate) < 2" style="color:#1ab394;" class="ng-binding"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 hours ago</small>
     <!--End of Issue to solve-->
</div>
```

First, the main mistake you are doing is that `setTimeout()` function is inside the `ReloadTime()` function. So the function is not called by `setTimeout()` unless you trigger that function once. So i disagree with the above answer. Secondly, the use of `$(this)` inside the `each` function reference to the individual `$('.NDateCount')` element so to achieve what you need, you first need to find the element `<small>` under `$(this)` and then get the `first()` element, and finally the `text()`